Impact of variation in the total number of samples when performing multiple fisher exact tests
I have dataset of 2 time points. In each time point I have to compare the counts of different components at each position (number of positions =1000). I used fisher exact test to compare the if there is a significant difference in the counts of the different components at the 2 time points. I ended up performing 1000 fisher test then I applied FDR correction. My questions are:
1.If the total number of samples used to compare between the 2 time points was varying significantly as in the picture below how that would affect the results? and the p value ? are there any bias?
2. how to fix this to get reliable result or is there any way for normalization or to account for this variation when performing fisher exact test ?
This is an example for more clarification, so for each position (each row in this image ) I performed fisher exact test and then applied FDR correction:

